# How to model the vehicle routing problem when customer demand exceeds vehicle capacity

Tags: optaplanner

I'm completely new to optaplanner and am looking for suggestions on how to model the vehicle routing problem in situations where the Customer’s demand exceeds the quantity of any single vehicle.   A simplistic example would be 1-depot, 1-truck (capacity 50) and 1-customer (demand 100).   The truck in this case obviously has to make two round trips to the customer, picking up 50 items each time.     It doesn’t look to me as if the vehiclerouting example handles these situations.

More generally, I have a depot, a fleet of vehicles each with an item carry capacity, and a collection of sites each with a quantity of items.    The vehicles need to collectively move all the items from the sites to the depot.    This is almost identical to the vehicle routing problem example but unless I’m missing something, the example doesn’t seem to account for the possibility that trucks may need to make multiple trips and visit the same customer site multiple times.    Is there another example that would be more appropriate?

On a side note, I think I could model this if I could make a list planning variable (Each vehicle could have a list of waypoints as the planning variable).   But it looks like this is not yet supported?

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-the-box VRP example in optaplanner-example indeed doesn't cover this.

A typical approach I see often is to figure out a "demand granularity". For example, given that your smallest vehicle type has capacity `50`, I 'd probably try first with a demandGranularity of `10`. So the single customer of demand `90` gets split up into 9 visits of 10. The single customer of demand `23` gets split up in to `10`, `10` and `3`.
Then just assign visits to vehicles like in optaplanner-examples's vrp example (Visit replaces Customer as the @PlanningEntity). Some tips:

- Use subChainSwap and subChainChange moves too (see docs chapter move selection).
- If there is a service time per visit and multiple visits at the same location only incur it once, use the design pattern "collapsing" (not sure if that's documented yet) to deal with that in the arrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.

Once you've implemented this and used optaplanner-benchmark to estimate it's value, then try demand granularity 15. Then try demand granularity 20, or 5. You're trading of potential solution quality vs performance vs solver spent time at that point. Look at the BEST_SCORE graph's to compare the effect of those demand granularity's.